# Prove that $ P \cup Q = Q$ and $P \cap Q = P$ if $P$ is a subset of $Q$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

When $P$ is a subset of $Q$, use logical connectives to

> 1. Prove $P \cup Q = Q$.
> 2. Prove $P \cap Q = P$.

I know that they are true, but I don't know how to use the definitions of union and intersection in terms of logical connectives to prove them.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One half of your question was asked here: [Prove that $A \subset B$ if and only if $A \cap B = A$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345252/prove-that-a-subset-b-if-and-only-if-a-cap-b-a). Several other equivalent conditions were given here: [Statements equivalent to $A\subset B$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/436442/statements-equivalent-to-a-subset-b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to break this down and look at it element by element?

If P is a subset of Q, then by definition, every element of P is an element of Q. So, as Q contains P, every element in either P or Q is in Q, so the union is Q.

For the second, every element of P and Q is in P, so the intersection is P.

Comment: I know that they are  true,  but i don't know how to use definitions of union and intersection in terms of logical connectives to prove them

Comment: I think you'd find that my answer actually contains those answers. Union works like 'or', intersection works like 'and'. If an element is in P and it is in Q, then it's in the intersection, etc.